# Weird frames appear when using TextureView to play video in ListView

Tags: android-listview, video-player, textureview

I managed to play multiple videos in one screen circularly, I added TextureViews to ListView with BaseAdapter which is very common and I created a IjkMediaPlayer ([IjkMediaplay github](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer))instance for each textureview. I have reused textureview in getView() callback of BaseAdapter, once getView() called, I stop the previous video and play the new video.

This works fine in most of time, but occasionally, TextureView will display some frames which is not belong to the current video, the frames display for very short time during the playback just like a flash.

With effort, I finally found where the strange frames come, they are from the video which is playing outside of the screen.
The weird frames will not appear if I push up the listview to make the outside textureview show up.

I have record a video to show the scene, in the video you will see 2 videos are playing circularly and a weird frame appear occasionally.
I assert that the weird frame(a white phone on the desk in the frame) is from the video below which is playing outside the screen.
[click to download the video](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1jGhFH5s)

Is this a bug of TextureView on Android, and how to avoid the weird playing?
Who can give me some advices?

Comment: I wouldn't jump to conclusions, but there have been reports of issues with multiple TextureViews -- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178525 .

Comment: @fadden
I am sorry that I didn't clarify the muti-thread. I start a HandlerThread for each textureview, and do all playing operations on that thread. I will draw the first frame(I save to the disk) of the video on the textureview by canvas.drawbitmap() and then call start() of IjkMediaPlayer instance.
In this way, it appears to be a smooth and quick startup for users.Is there anything wrong with multi-thread?

Comment: I want to tell that the probability of the flicker is very low.

Comment: The other reports had equivalent behavior when single-threaded, so if it's the same thing then being multi-threaded won't matter. The only reason I raised it on the earlier issues was to rule out race conditions in the app itself; the framework shouldn't have thread limitations here. Again, I wouldn't jump to the conclusion that it's the same problem, but it's worth checking for similarities and looking at the workarounds in the associated stackoverflow questions.

Comment: @fadden
I have refered to the similar question and realized that invalidate() can fix the flicker. But I tried it and nothing changed. Then I looked into the source code of TextureView and found that invalidate() will be called once every video frame get available. So invalidate() is called all the time for textureView which is playing video. I am sad to discover the fact.

Comment: @fadden
I said that the probability of the flicker is very low before. That is wrong!
This flicker can be reproduced with some steps very easily on some devices such as mi note. And for some other phones, the flicker can not be seen.

Comment: I have observed a similar issue ...but one was a camera rendering on a textureview and other was rendered from NDK c++ code and the camera frames used to appear on the video view a times. If there are two textureview rendered on the screen, both with NDK render..then i dont see the problem. For me it was something to do with camera driver intercepting the other textureview window. Havent found a solution ..except for device upgrade...that works , atleast for nexus 7 2012 model

Comment: @fadden
I have refered to your DoubleDecodeActivity and found you used MediaExtractor to decode video, but I use IjkPlayer to decode. So in order to solve this problem, I plan to use MediaExtractor to decode and see the result. I know that the API MediaPlayer and MediaExtractor both decode with hardware, but what difference between them? I found MediaPlayer takes nearly 1000ms to start a video on some devices(this is why I chose ijkplayer), will MediaExtractor play as slow as MediaPlayer on the same device?

Comment: I don't know why MediaPlayer would start slowly, so I can't say if there will or won't be a difference.

Comment: @fadden
I tried Android MediaPlayer instead of ijkplayer, the flicker also appears.  But after lots of struggles, I solved this ficker at last and the result is good! After I fixed this problem, no one encounter this flicker any more though millions of people are using this function.

Comment: @dragonfly Con you add your solution? It will be helpful for other users also,  like me. and I am also facing same issue in IjkMediaPlayer. and its only happening when I use seekTo method ~thanks

Comment: @dastan According to your words, I think your situation does not match this flicker.